# What does CoAP Max transaction in Contiki means?

Tags: rest, transactions, contiki, coap

I didn't get whether Max transactions refer to client side or server side of CoAP. For instance, if COAP_MAX_OPEN_TRANSACTIONS is 4. Does it mean that CoAP Client can send 4 parallel request to different servers or it means that CoAP Server can process max 4 requests in parallel.

Because from the code I see that it initiates a blocking request from the client side which will not allow looping for another transaction.

So, need clarification here. If multiple CoAP transactions possible from client side then please mention how. Thank you.

Comment: At the protocol level, you can do multiple transactions from client side. `coap_send_transaction()` is asynchronous, for example. You would need to reimplement bits from `COAP_BLOCKING_REQUEST()` for that.

Answer (score 1):

According to paper dunkels.com/adam/kovatsch11low-power.pdf
Section III-F **CoAP Clients** provide a blocking function call implemented with protothreads to issue a request. This linear programming model can also hide blockwise transfers, as it continues first when all data were received. So based on this I am guessing client can generate one transaction at a time and blocks to wait for ack (or timeout).

Here is code reference https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/blob/master/apps/er-coap/er-coap-engine.c#L370.

Contrarily, Server can respond to multiple transactions simultaneously because there are transactions which wait for response (from say sensors) and need to save state. This is my understanding of the question posted. If I am wrong then please correct.

Answer (score 0):

According to links:

https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/blob/bc2e445817aa546c0bb93a9900093ec276005e2a/apps/er-coap/er-coap-conf.h#L51

https://github.com/contiki-ng/contiki-ng/wiki/Documentation:-CoAP#configuration

I guess it's just a max number of confirmable requests (which have not yet received an ACK) to be stored simultaneously for retransmission.

And it used for reserving memory for the max number of those requests:

https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/blob/3f4436bac9a9f6da0df188372d4374693eab8a52/apps/er-coap/er-coap-transactions.c#L57

```
MEMB(transactions_memb, coap_transaction_t, COAP_MAX_OPEN_TRANSACTIONS);
```

Comment: Yes that is correct but the question is still unanswered. Can client do multiple transactions or not?

Comment: According to http://dunkels.com/adam/kovatsch11low-power.pdf Section III-F CoAP Clients provide a blocking function call implemented with protothreads to issue a request. This linear programming model can also hide blockwise transfers,
as it continues first when all data were received. So based on this I am guessing client can generate one transaction at a time and blocks to wait for ack (or timeout). Contrarily, Server can respond to multiple transactions simultaneously because there are trans which wait for response and need queuing. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: HI_205, if you consider you've found a real answer which is better than others, please don't hesitate to share it as an answer here and accept. This will help others who will look for similar stuff.